# How can I use datediff of mysql with sequelizejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to implement this SQL to my Sequelize

```
SELECT file_id FROM table WHERE datediff(curdate(),create_date) > 5;

   Here is my Sequelize

   findOverPeriodFile: function () {
    return table.findAll({
        where:{
            60: {lt: Sequelize.fn('')}
        }
    });
}
```

Im new to Seuelize and I have tried to search Google, but it doesn't help. Does anyone have an answer to this question? I don't know what to put in the `WHERE` statement. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you go :

You can generate `WHERE datediff(curdate(),create_date) > 5;` by using :

```
{ 
    where: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('datediff', sequelize.fn("NOW") , sequelize.col('create_date')), {
        $gt : 5 // OR [Op.gt] : 5
    })
}
```

---

**For adding more condition**

```
{
    where: {
        $and : [
            sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('datediff', sequelize.fn("NOW") , sequelize.col('create_date')), {
                $gt : 5 // OR [Op.gt] : 5
            }) ,
            { status : 'mystatus' }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: But I tried using [Op.gt] :5 and it worked. Btw, thanks for your help :D

Comment: How do you add more where clauses to this ? eg. `<DATEDIFF> AND status = 'mystatus'`

Comment: Thanks @VivekDoshi for the quick reply :) I was just about to comment about one of the solution I found at https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7535#issuecomment-441021531.

Comment: Also the above "adding more condition" seems to be throwing me syntax errors. Maybe the `$and` should be after `sequelize.where` ?

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa, yeah, my mistake , check now.

Answer (score 1):

```
sequelize.where(
    sequelize.fn(
        'timestampdiff', 
         sequelize.literal("minute"),
         sequelize.col('updatedAt'),
         sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')
    ), 
    {
        [Op.gte] : ACCEPTION_TIMEOUT
    }
)
```

If someone like me will be searching for a way to find date or time difference in sequelize (not only in days), **timestampdiff** is a working way to do that.

`sequelize.literal("minute")` — is a unit of time. More on that [here](https://database.guide/timestampdiff-examples-mysql/)

`sequelize.col('updatedAt')` — column in the database (datetime)

`sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')` — sequelize literal for current time

```
{
   [Op.gte] : ACCEPTION_TIMEOUT
}
```

And this one is your SELECT condition for time matters

Answer (score 0):

```
sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('datediff', sequelize.literal("day"), sequelize.col('Your Column date'), sequelize.fn("getdate")), {
          [Op.gt]: 0
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

for Microsoft SQL Server (MSSQL) This one worked for me. Thanks to @Vivek Doshi

```
let pending = await Table.findAll({
        where: {
            [Op.and] : [
                Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('datediff',  Sequelize.col('DD'), Sequelize.col('createdAt'), Sequelize.fn("GETDATE")), {
                    [Op.lt] : 1 
                }) ,
                { is_processed : '0' }
            ]
        }
    } );
```

This will generate

```
SELECT * FROM [table] AS [table] 
WHERE (datediff(DD, [createdAt], GETDATE()) < 1 AND [table].[is_processed] = 0);
```

Which is exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

```
where: {
        [Op.and]: [
          sequelize.where(
            sequelize.fn(
              "datediff",
              sequelize.fn("NOW"),
              sequelize.col("lastSubmitted") // your column name 
            ),
            {
              [Op.gt]: 1,
            }
          ),
          {status:"active"},
        ],
}
```

Remeber to import OP from Sequelize and **it's not a default export.**

This should do the work, I was using **$and** and **$gt** before, but they didn't work.